# Punctuation for a story read aloud within a story

Tags: punctuation

I have written a fairy tale in which another person reads a story aloud within the tale itself. Do I need quotation marks around the entire story within the story? If I need to at all, how do I punctuate it?

Comment: Indent the whole story.  "Block quote".

Answer (score 2):

> I would say, "Start the story like any other line that a character says. The way I've formatted this quote is standard for American English, but where your commas go depends on the region. Either way, it works for the most part like a normal line of dialogue at the beginning and end, just with a little bit of funky stuff in the middle.
>
> "To start a new paragraph in the same quote, put quotation marks before the new paragraph but not after the old one. I don't know why this is the rule, but it is. 'How, then,' you might ask, 'would I include quotation within the story?' Do everything totally normally, and use a single inverted comma instead of a double one. If you use the apostrophe key on your keyboard, smart quotes usually figure out how to orient the little ticks."

That was incredibly extra, but that's the standard for long stories within novels and stuff. Pretty much just format the beginning and end normally, start new paragraphs with a ", and alternate the number of tick marks any time someone speaks within the quote (if I said, "She asked, 'Why do cows say "Moo"?'", that's how I'd do the ""s)

Comment: I edited your answer to use block quotes (>) rather than preformatted text. It makes it much easier to read. (A space is added between block quotes by adding two spaces at the end of the previous paragraph.)

Comment: Note that the block quotes above is an example of how the OP's "story" should be formatted within the text of the "fairy tale".